# Delete a report from an mdb file without using automation

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ado.net, office-automation

I know that I can delete a report from *within* Access VBA:

```
DoCmd.DeleteObject acReport, "SomeReport"
```

I also know that I can delete a report from *outside* Access by using automation (VB.NET example):

```
Set acc = CreateObject("Access.Application")
acc.OpenCurrentDatabase(...)
Set db = acc.CurrentDb()

' Enumerate db.Containers("Reports").Documents to find the report name
...

acc.DoCmd.DeleteObject(acReport, reportName)
```

I also know that I can access Access *tables* with ADO.NET (i.e. without automation).

My question is: **Can I delete a report from an Access database file *without* using automation?**

---

Notes:

- In case it makes a difference: I'm stuck with legacy mdb databases at the moment, but if there's an accdb-only solution, I'd be curious about that as well.
- Officially sanctioned solutions are preferred, but, if there are none, well-proven hacks (e.g. modifying MSysObjects in some way) or undocumented features are acceptable as well.
- If you are wondering *why* I want to do this: The automation solution has a few drawbacks (indeterminism if multiple Access versions are installed; AutoExec is run if present; user interface messages might pop up; etc.) which I'd rather avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you can't. You have listed the options.

Neither can the system tables be modified directly.

But you could export a modified form which has had the option for opening the report disabled and hidden, thus effectively making the report inaccessible for the user.